# Separating points with identical coordinates using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, point, coordinates

I need to move apart points with identical coordinates.

I have a point layer where there can be as high as 4 points on each other (same coordinate). I want to separate these points from each other (with a defined distance in x and y), using a pyscript. Right now, only the script's first part (Part 1) works, but then for some reason the script stops moving points at the second "cursor loop".
Is there a better way to solve the task?

```
#------------------------------------------------------
#Enviroments
    import arcpy
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    workspace = r"*"
    arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
    fc = "*"
    fields = ['SHAPE@X', 'SHAPE@Y']


    #Copy feature class:
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, fc + "Copy")
    #Set FC to Copied data
    fcCopy = fc + "Copy"

    edit = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)

    ----------------------Part 1----------------------

    Xlist1 = []
    Ylist1 = []
    edit.startEditing(False, False)

    edit.startOperation()
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fcCopy, fields) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[0] in Xlist1 and row[1] in Ylist1:
                row[0] = row[0] + 10.0 #Move the point 10 meters in X
            if row[0] not in Xlist1 and row[1] not in Ylist1:
                Xlist1.append(row[0])
                Ylist1.append(row[1])
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        print(Xlist1, Ylist1)
        del row
        del cursor
    edit.stopOperation()
    edit.stopEditing(True)

    print("Script Part Done 1")

#----------------------Part 2 ----------------------

Xlist = []
Ylist = []

    edit.startEditing(False, False)
    edit.startOperation()
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fcCopy, fields) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[0] in Xlist and row[1] in Ylist:
                row[1] = row[1] + 10.0   #Move the point 10 meters in Y
            if row[0] not in Xlist and row[1] not in Ylist:
                Xlist.append(row[0])
                Ylist.append(row[1])
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        del row
        del cursor
    edit.stopOperation()
    edit.stopEditing(True)



    print("Script Part Done 2")
```

From
[image]

To:

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot showing how you want the four coordiantes in the same spot to end up?

Comment: Hi, approx like this this

Answer (score 2):

You have this set up correctly, where you essentially "skip over" the first point at a given location and then move subsequent points at that location.  The problem I think is that your xlist and ylist are independent, so you could have a coordinate with no duplicates show up as being in there if EACH of its x and y coordinates matches another point.  Also it's unnecessary to start an edit session as the da module will update the data directly without that.

Using your own approach, you could change "Part 1" to accomplish both x and y movements, and sidestep the issue of independent x and y lists with the zip command:

```
Xlist1 = Ylist1 = []
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fcCopy, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if (row[0], row[1]) in zip(Xlist1, Ylist1):
            row[0] = row[0] + 10.0 #Move the point 10 meters in X
            row[1] = row[1] + 10.0
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        else:
            Xlist1.append(row[0])
            Ylist1.append(row[1])
        cursor.updateRow(row)
    print(Xlist1, Ylist1)
```